# How to change app.js data from the child component by select option with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, onchange

I'm havin a Tasklist component with a nested tasks inside as a child components. I'm trying to change the App.js data - status by selecting the option in the TaskComponent template. So I need to modify data with a function a maybe send its props to the App.js component. But I can't see how to do it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-24-04-vp0v8m?file=/src/components/TaskComponent.js

```
// Child component TasksComponent

const TaskComponent = ({ Tasks }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const task = Tasks.find((task) => String(task.id) === id);
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
        <label>Status</label>
        <select
          onChange={"change this individual task's status to selected option"}  // trying to set this line
        >
          <option value="0">In queue</option>
          <option value="1">In progress</option>
          <option value="2">Completed</option>
        </select>
        <button>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// App.js component

const Tasks = [
  {
    id: "001",
    status: 0,
    priority: 2,
    title: "Develop website homepage",
    description:
      "Create a visually appealing and responsive homepage for the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-23T10:00:00"
    },
    author_name: "John Smith"
  },
  {
    id: "002",
    status: 1,
    priority: 1,
    title: "Implement user authentication",
    description: "Add user authentication feature to the website",
    schedule: {
      creation_time: "2021-07-24T14:30:00"
    },
    author_name: "Sarah Lee"
  }
]

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/task/:id">
            <TaskComponent Tasks={tasks} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I'm expecting to change the individual status key to be changed when selecting the option in the Child Component with an onChange method.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in your `select` inside the `onChange` you're executing the `changeTask` instead of passing callback function. Replace this:

```
<select onChange={changeTask(task.priority)}>
    <option value="select" disabled>Select Priority</option>
    <option value="0">Low</option>
    <option value="1">Medium</option>
    <option value="2">High</option>
</select>
```

For this on the 2 `select` elements you have in `TaskComponent.js`:

```
<select onChange={() => changeTask(task.priority)}>
    <option value="select" disabled>Select Priority</option>
    <option value="0">Low</option>
    <option value="1">Medium</option>
    <option value="2">High</option>
</select>
```

This way the `changeTask` function will run only when the value of the select changes.